# Updating UI while importing large data sets in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, user-interface, core-data

In my app I have a function that will download a large data set from a server into Core Data. It looks something like this:

```
for (PFObject *historyObject in historyArray) {
    History *history = (History *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"History" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    history.date = historyObject.date;
    // ...
}
```

Because this can take a few minutes I want to update UI in the process and show the user the progress that has been made.
Now because inserting this data into Core Data is blocking the main thread I am not sure if there is another proper way to update the UI.

I have tried several methods of moving the insertion into a different thread but have always had problems with Core Date responding with errors.

I hope somebody out there has a good idea and would like to share it.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what you tried when you moved over to a background thread? As a warning, your app WILL be rejected if you block the main thread in any way.

Comment: I used dispatch_async() for example. And I think we tried performSelectorInBackground:

Comment: i would recommend of reading some on NSRunLoop class, it can help you in that scenario.

Comment: You **MUST** share details. What type of errors you have? What type of concurrency model you're using, traditional or parent-child?

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with all the comments here. Core data is an incredibly powerful framework especially when used in a multi-threaded environment. If I were you I would take a look at MagicRecord on GitHub as they would be the quickest solution for you. Otherwise you can setup a save context with the confinement type set to Private

Comment: Basically a context is created and all operations performed on the managed objects must occur on that context that's why NSManagedObjectContext has the performBlock method. You should always be updating or creating your objects for a background context inside these methods

Comment: http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html happy reading

Comment: @DanielGalasko In fact I asked for further info since the question is not complete.

Comment: @flexaddicted I wasn't referring to your post since you weren't providing a vague answer like the other posters. Milo and Nadav specifically detailed incorrect answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have currently solved this by initializing the ManagedObjectContext with concurrency type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and setting the parent context to the main ManagedObjectContext. 
For anybody having the same problem:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
    _backgroundMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_backgroundMOC setParentContext:[kDelegate managedObjectContext]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [cars count]; i++)
    {
        [_backgroundMOC performBlockAndWait:^{

            Drive *drive = (Drive *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Drive" inManagedObjectContext:_backgroundMOC.parentContext];

            ....do more stuff...

        }];
    }

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:((float)i/(float)[cars count])] waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

For this to work you will have to change the managedObjectContext in the AppDelegate:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) 
    {
    return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) 
    {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```